# Facebook sharing offline

Tags: php, facebook, offline

I made a web application in PHP that posts images to my Facebook pages.
Everything works if I'm online and press POST button.

Now what I wanted to do is:

- upload image to my server
- choose one of my Facebook pages
- enter a message (text)
- pick time I want the app to post this image to the chosen Facebook page (using RCON).

I know how to program those things but I fail when the script is called via RCON.
The script doesn't have access token so I can't post anything.

Is there any way how script can get access token to post images to my Facebook pages when I'm off with my friends?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say 'page', or you talking about a Facebook page?

Comment: Yes, I mean Facebook page. I'll edit my previous post.

Comment: Do you want to upload _as_ the page, or under your own user account? In the first case, get a page access token and store it in your app, they don’t expire. In the second case, get a long-lived user access token – and renew it regularly somewhere within the 60 day period.